# How do I get only the first element of matching elements from Dataframe without iterating through it?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, set

Suppose I have a dataframe as such:

```
   Var0  Var1
0    11    22      <--------- Get 1st element of matching
1    11    84
2     8    36      <--------- Get 1st element of matching
3     8     8
4     8    10
5     6    12      <--------- Get 1st element of matching
```

I want to get this result:

```
   Var0  Var1
0    11    22
2     8    36
5     6    12
```

First I sort my dataframe by `sort_values()`:

```
df.sort_values(['Var0'], ascending=['False'])
```

I think im suppose to use `set` but not sure where to do it. 
I do not want to iterate through the dataframe due to speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use duplicates:

```
df[~df['Var0'].duplicated()]

print(df)

  Var0  Var1
0    11    22
2     8    36
5     6    12
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this just `drop_duplicates`

```
df.drop_duplicates('Var0')
Out[230]: 
   Var0  Var1
0    11    22
2     8    36
5     6    12
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also `groupby` with the `.head` method:

```
df = df.groupby('Var0', sort=False, as_index=False).head(1)

print(df)
   Var0  Var1
0    11    22
1     8    36
2     6    12
```

Comment: Just a small tips , maybe you can using head(1) rather than first , since head will record the index information as well, still a good one :-)++

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `pd.Series.searchsorted` (or `numpy.searchsorted`).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5]})
values = [1, 3, 4, 5]  # we want to find first occurrence indices for these values

common_values = np.intersect1d(data.x.values, values)
print(common_values) # get common values 

print(data.x.searchsorted(common_values))

print(data.loc[data.x.searchsorted(common_values)])
```